# Jmeter - why linux gives different answer than windows?

Tags: redirect, jmeter

I wrote a test plan on Windows 7. I remotely started a test on two machines, both Windows Vista. A problem came up when I tried do same thing on Linux - I used the same test plan.

I can login a group of users and simulate their behaviour, but when I try to log them out nothing happens.

On windows, they are logout but linux gives me empty response data. Listeners show green status so I'm rather confused to what's going on. Should I change something in properties or is it problem with my script?

EDIT:

Script:

1. Login user using authorization data. every user gets different JSESSIONID.
2. Simulate user behaviour using Access Log Sampler.
3. Logout user.

On Windows, everything works fine login and logout. Listener shows: sample result, request data and response data for every sample.

On linux response data is blank for every sample.

Examples of Sample result for
[windows](http://www.screencast.com/t/ibqFk9xRKuux) and
[linux](http://www.screencast.com/t/sA4Ogosg)

Request Data is the same for both.

Response data for linux is blank.

EDIT2:

- Test Plan

  - setUP Thread Group

    - Clean cache server
    - Clean file with JSESSIONID
  - Thread Group

    - HTTP Request Defaults
    - Login (once only controller)
    - Acces Log Sampler
    - using beanshell script i save JSESSIONID (cookie variable) to file
    - Cookie Manager
  - tearDown Thread Group

    - HTTP Request Defaults
    - read JSESSIONID from file
    - logout all users
    - Cookie Manager
  - result tree
  - Summary report

Logout must be performed after all samples from access log are done. That's why i save JSESSIONID to file to share same session between thread group.

Ok somehow I eliminate error with response. Apparently there was a problem with java version on linux server.

Current problem is that when i start remotely script on Linux it doesn't follow redirect. The same script on win XP or Vista follow redirects and user is logout.
Exp.

```
GET connection.rpc?logout=D5D076123FD6CCBF137FE1673F531006
```

On Windows I get two redirections and user is logout.

```
Thread Name: Logout 1-1
Sample Start: 2013-05-18 13:50:52 CEST
Load time: 15
Latency: 13
Size in bytes: 777
Headers size in bytes: 573
Body size in bytes: 204
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-wkpl-server-name: OnlineRC2
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 204
Date: Sat, 18 May 2013 11:50:43 GMT


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html;charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8

Thread Name:
Sample Start: 2013-05-18 13:50:52 CEST
Load time: 13
Latency: 13
Size in bytes: 374
Headers size in bytes: 374
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 302
Response message: Moved Temporarily

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6D3F7A3774ABB1411A5F8E1744004A71; Path=/WKPLOnline
CacheControl: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache, no-store
Expires: -1
Location: connection.rpc?logout=BE8C04D8538641675A8BFD2490CDDD4D
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 18 May 2013 11:50:43 GMT

Thread Name: Logout 1-1
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

Sample Start: 2013-05-18 13:50:52 CEST
Load time: 2
Latency: 2
Size in bytes: 403
Headers size in bytes: 199
Body size in bytes: 204
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-wkpl-server-name: OnlineRC2
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 204
Date: Sat, 18 May 2013 11:50:43 GMT


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html;charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8
```

On Linux I don't get redirects and user is not logout.

```
Thread Name: Logout 1-1
Sample Start: 2013-05-18 13:51:48 CEST
Load time: 18
Latency: 18
Size in bytes: 264
Headers size in bytes: 243
Body size in bytes: 21
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=D17A4ABCDE7FB90C1DF702BDCB3827D7; Path=/WKPLOnline
CacheControl: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache, no-store
Expires: -1
Content-Length: 21
Date: Sat, 18 May 2013 11:51:53 GMT


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

It is strange because during authorization there are a few redirects and linux performs them correctly.

Comment: Could you provide more information? This is hardly enough to go on.

Comment: I add more information

Comment: Show your test plan structure and if you can show response tab in view tree result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solve, yupi :)
It turned out that the target server has set the lock for some machines. On such a machine was a Linux. That is why I could not log users in a separate thread.

Therefore, if someone encounters a similar problem (from one machine request are handled correctly from another are not), he should check if his machine have correct permission in my case i needed to do correct entry in adm.list in test server.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that jmeter accesses correctly your jsessionid file on linux:

- check path is ok (no )
- check read access

If you are using distributed testing, issue may be that file is not found by agent or some file is overwritten by another agent

Comment: I think that path and read access is ok because i request i get correct value. Everytime i send:
GET connection.rpc?logout=D5D076123FD6CCBF137FE1673F531006
and for every other request fraze after "logout=" is change for right text from file.